# how to query corda vault and retrieve states based on a field that contains a string pattern

Tags: fetch, state, corda, builder, vault

I have a state with customer id and customer name as a field.
The requirement is to query vault and fetch customer id for customer names
that contain a certain string pattern like 'ash'. Like in sql query we search for a pattern in the format '%ash%'.
is this possible in vault querying? if yes , then what should the syntax be?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was answered on our slack instance (slack.corda.net for anyone using corda)

Try setting up a query that looks like this:

```java
new QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(Builder.like("%"+inputCustomerName+"%",customerName));
```

note: thanks to Corda user Amol Pednekar for his help on this question from slack.